# MakeFile using implicit rules error

Tags: c++, makefile

Trying to assemble Makefile for my project. I am using [Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules) for object files, but running `make compile` fails and following error is generated:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb ./main.o ./AI.o ./BoardData.o ./Circle.o ./Coordination.o ./Cross.o ./GameField.o ./GameLogic.o ./GraficObject.o ./INetwork.o ./IUserInterface.o ./LocalHuman.o ./LocalPlayer.o ./NetworkException.o ./NetworkTCP.o ./NetworkTCPClient.o ./NetworkTCPServer.o ./Player.o ./PlayerRotator.o ./RemotePlayer.o ./Stone.o ./UserInterfaceNcurse.o -o ./game -lcurses
g++: error: ./main.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./AI.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./BoardData.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./Circle.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./Coordination.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./Cross.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./GameField.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./GameLogic.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./GraficObject.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./INetwork.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./IUserInterface.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./LocalHuman.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./LocalPlayer.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./NetworkException.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./NetworkTCP.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./NetworkTCPClient.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./NetworkTCPServer.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./Player.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./PlayerRotator.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./RemotePlayer.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./Stone.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./UserInterfaceNcurse.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [game] Error 1
```

Here's my MakeFile:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb
CXXLIBS=-lcurses
OBJECTS= ./main.o ./AI.o ./BoardData.o ./Circle.o ./Coordination.o ./Cross.o \
    ./GameField.o ./GameLogic.o ./GraficObject.o ./INetwork.o ./IUserInterface.o \
    ./LocalHuman.o ./LocalPlayer.o ./NetworkException.o ./NetworkTCP.o \
    ./NetworkTCPClient.o ./NetworkTCPServer.o ./Player.o ./PlayerRotator.o \
    ./RemotePlayer.o ./Stone.o ./UserInterfaceNcurse.o
DOXYFILE=./doxyfile
BINARY=./game
SOURCE_DIR=./src/
DOC_DIR=./doc/

################################################################################

.PHONY : all
.PHONY : compile
.PHONY : run
.PHONY : clean
.PHONY : doc

################################################################################

all: $(OBJECTS) $(DOXYFILE)
    make compile
    make doc

compile: $(BINARY)

run: $(BINARY)
    $(BINARY)

clean:
    -rm -rf $(DOC_DIR) $(BINARY) $(OBJECTS)

doc: $(DOXYFILE)
    -mkdir $(DOC_DIR)
    doxygen $(DOXYFILE)

################################################################################

$(BINARY): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(BINARY) $(CXXLIBS)

################################################################################

## Using Implicit Rules for all object files
## Generated by g++ -MM ./src/*.cpp

main.o: ./src/main.cpp ./src/IUserInterface.h ./src/Coordination.h \
 ./src/UserInterfaceNcurse.h ./src/GraficObject.h ./src/Cross.h ./src/Stone.h \
 ./src/Circle.h ./src/GameField.h ./src/LocalHuman.h ./src/LocalPlayer.h \
 ./src/Player.h ./src/INetwork.h ./src/GameLogic.h ./src/BoardData.h ./src/AI.h \
 ./src/RemotePlayer.h ./src/PlayerRotator.h ./src/NetworkTCPClient.h \
 ./src/NetworkTCP.h ./src/NetworkException.h ./src/NetworkTCPServer.h
AI.o: ./src/AI.cpp ./src/AI.h ./src/LocalPlayer.h ./src/Player.h \
 ./src/IUserInterface.h ./src/Coordination.h ./src/INetwork.h ./src/GameLogic.h \
 ./src/BoardData.h ./src/Stone.h ./src/GraficObject.h
BoardData.o: ./src/BoardData.cpp ./src/BoardData.h ./src/Coordination.h
Circle.o: ./src/Circle.cpp ./src/Circle.h ./src/Stone.h ./src/GraficObject.h \
 ./src/IUserInterface.h ./src/Coordination.h
Coordination.o: ./src/Coordination.cpp ./src/Coordination.h
Cross.o: ./src/Cross.cpp ./src/Cross.h ./src/Stone.h ./src/GraficObject.h \
 ./src/IUserInterface.h ./src/Coordination.h
GameField.o: ./src/GameField.cpp ./src/GameField.h ./src/GraficObject.h \
 ./src/IUserInterface.h ./src/Coordination.h
GameLogic.o: ./src/GameLogic.cpp ./src/GameLogic.h ./src/BoardData.h \
 ./src/Coordination.h
GraficObject.o: ./src/GraficObject.cpp ./src/GraficObject.h \
 ./src/IUserInterface.h ./src/Coordination.h
INetwork.o: ./src/INetwork.cpp ./src/INetwork.h ./src/Coordination.h
IUserInterface.o: ./src/IUserInterface.cpp ./src/IUserInterface.h \
 ./src/Coordination.h
LocalHuman.o: ./src/LocalHuman.cpp ./src/LocalHuman.h ./src/LocalPlayer.h \
 ./src/Player.h ./src/IUserInterface.h ./src/Coordination.h ./src/INetwork.h \
 ./src/GameLogic.h ./src/BoardData.h ./src/Stone.h ./src/GraficObject.h
LocalPlayer.o: ./src/LocalPlayer.cpp ./src/LocalPlayer.h ./src/Player.h \
 ./src/IUserInterface.h ./src/Coordination.h ./src/INetwork.h ./src/GameLogic.h \
 ./src/BoardData.h ./src/Stone.h ./src/GraficObject.h
NetworkException.o: ./src/NetworkException.cpp ./src/NetworkException.h
NetworkTCPClient.o: ./src/NetworkTCPClient.cpp ./src/NetworkTCPClient.h \
 ./src/NetworkTCP.h ./src/INetwork.h ./src/Coordination.h \
 ./src/NetworkException.h
NetworkTCP.o: ./src/NetworkTCP.cpp ./src/NetworkTCP.h ./src/INetwork.h \
 ./src/Coordination.h
NetworkTCPServer.o: ./src/NetworkTCPServer.cpp ./src/NetworkTCPServer.h \
 ./src/NetworkTCP.h ./src/INetwork.h ./src/Coordination.h \
 ./src/NetworkException.h
Player.o: ./src/Player.cpp ./src/Player.h ./src/IUserInterface.h \
 ./src/Coordination.h ./src/INetwork.h ./src/GameLogic.h ./src/BoardData.h \
 ./src/Stone.h ./src/GraficObject.h
PlayerRotator.o: ./src/PlayerRotator.cpp ./src/PlayerRotator.h ./src/Player.h \
 ./src/IUserInterface.h ./src/Coordination.h ./src/INetwork.h ./src/GameLogic.h \
 ./src/BoardData.h ./src/Stone.h ./src/GraficObject.h
RemotePlayer.o: ./src/RemotePlayer.cpp ./src/RemotePlayer.h ./src/Player.h \
 ./src/IUserInterface.h ./src/Coordination.h ./src/INetwork.h ./src/GameLogic.h \
 ./src/BoardData.h ./src/Stone.h ./src/GraficObject.h
Stone.o: ./src/Stone.cpp ./src/Stone.h ./src/GraficObject.h \
 ./src/IUserInterface.h ./src/Coordination.h
UserInterfaceNcurse.o: ./src/UserInterfaceNcurse.cpp \
 ./src/UserInterfaceNcurse.h ./src/IUserInterface.h ./src/Coordination.h \
 ./src/GraficObject.h
```

Comment: Did ... Did you wrote all this by hand ?

Comment: @Chnossos Except the last part ... yes

Comment: does adding a pattern rule for .cpp to .o compilation solve the problem?

Comment: Ok so now, are your source files the current directory or in the `src` directory ? And why do you generate your `.o` rules beforehand and then copy/paste them in your Makefile instead of letting the Makefile handle that step automatically ?

Comment: @doron If by pattern rule you mean `$(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXLIBS) -o $@ $<` under every object file definition, then yes. But with implicit rules this should not be necessery.

Comment: @Chnossos That's another problem :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488571/makefile-using-implicit-rules-add-directory-path-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rely more on automated tools Make provides you.

I think your real problem here is that your source files are in the `src` directory, and your `OBJECTS` variable lists them in the current (`.`) directory.

Also, you are actually calling your own makefile recursively, which can be avoided.

Also +1 for using suitable `CXX*` variables ...

Ok so now :

```perl
BINARY  :=  game # `:=` operator prevents further expansion

DOC_DIR :=  doc
DOC     :=  doxyfile

SRC_DIR :=  src
SRC     :=  $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp) # Automatically lists all .cpp files

OBJ_DIR :=  build
OBJ     :=  $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o) # i.e. src/toto.cpp -> build/toto.o

DEP     :=  $(OBJ:.o=.d) # i.e. build/toto.o -> build/toto.d

# No need to redefine $(CXX) which already contains "g++"

CPPFLAGS    :=  -MMD -MP # Will auto-generate dependencies along with the linking step

CXXFLAGS    :=  -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb

LDFLAGS     :=  # -L flags

LDLIBS      :=  -lcurses # -l flags

.PHONY: all doc run clean

# We want to build the binary and the doc when typing "make"
all: $(BINARY) doc

# The binary requires compiling the sources
$(BINARY): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

# We want to create the "build" directory only once, before compiling the source files
# Create a build/.o and build/.d files for a given src/.cpp file, with dependency generation
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJ_DIR):
    @mkdir $@

-include $(DEP) # includes auto-generated dependency rules

doc:
    @mkdir -p $(DOC_DIR) # -p to avoid getting an error if it exists
    doxygen $(DOC)

run: $(BINARY)
    ./$(BINARY)
```

Comment: Found what i was looking for http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html . I will review all changes first with documentation.

Comment: I just have 2 questions. When is exactly `-include $(DEP) # includes auto-generated dependency rules` called and when are *.d files gerated (I guess during `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp`. And the dir location is always is the same with *.o files)?

Comment: The `.d` files are indeed generated within that rule, along with the `.o` files. You can change the location if needed with the `-MF` option. Usually I prefer hiding these files in a hidden `.obj` folder. `-include $(DEP)` is expanded into `-include file1.d file2.d ...`. As to when it is called, I don't know exactly, but you can learn more [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html).